# Polygonal particles in Winforms (particles.js)

Tags: javascript, c#

I recently started to learn C#.

In the Internet, I came across the so-called "animated polygonal particles." There is also a particles.js service on the Internet that provides the ability to use polygonal particles. Are there any such analogues, but only for C# (winforms)? If not, is it possible to somehow make them animated polygonal particles in Winforms?
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDSyS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a browser viewport on your WinForm and then use that JS inside of it; it will animate.  I’m not sure this is a good answer; but it would work.